# Unable to follow an Area 51 proposal after turning from Guest into logged in user and unfollowing

Tags: bug, area-51, login, user-accounts, unregistered-users

I am trying to follow Prestashop under Area 51. I clicked follow, it gave me an email, I confirmed it, and it made a guest account. I didn't want to follow as a guest, so I unfollowed it, and then I logged in. It turned my guest example question into a question from me. Issue is, I am not unable to follow it. I can follow it, but it doesn't show me as a follower, and the number of followers stay the same, where as before I logged in with my stack account, I was affecting the number. I'd like to support a Prestashop stack site. Am I doing something wrong, or can this be fixed?

Comment: Can't believe I forgot my own answer, after only year and half. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, I need to verify my email with Area 51 before my Follows take effect. This was unexpected, as I've already verified my email with Stack Exchange, and since using the same account with the same company, did not expect to have to verify my email again for this site, nor did anything say to me that I was receiving an email to verify the account. I believe this is an issue.

Comment: Probably the Verify Email process is per account (not per email), so not sure it's really a bug.

Comment: Not a bug, but confusing, or at the very least, something unintuitive that could be improved.